# Type Error. Cannot react property '0' undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the genre of a movie fron an API

Here is the response

[image]

I am getting this error (image below) which I think is because the page is trying to display the genre before the request was able to insert it in the useState (I useState to store the api response and then grab that current state and display it to the page)

[image]

Here is where I render the data from the useState

[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `movieDetails` to be there to actually render it.

I suggest you do something like this:

```
const MovieDetails = (props) => {
  const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {

   // get your data asynchronously

   setMovieDetails(data)

  }, []) // when the component mounts

  return !movieDetails
    ? <div>loading...</div>
    : (
      <div>
        <h1>{movieDetails.title}</h1>
        <h3>{movieDetails.overview}</h3>
        {movieDetails.genres[0] && <h1>{movieDetails.genres[0].name}</h1>}
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </div>
    )

}
```

Also, you can create another state in case there are errors while fetching the data. And bonus points: abstracting this away in a general hook called i.e. `useFetchData` that returns something like `{ data, loading, error }`

Comment: Instead of this `movieDetails.genres[0] && [...]` i would first and foremost check if genre was populated `movieDetails.genres && [...]`.

Comment: Of course, all the checks need to be done, that was just an example... I'd use the optional chaining